What to log as consecutive number of flight for aircraft logbook?
In GA flying as part of flight clubs, how do you usually number the flights logged in the aircraft logbook? At my local club, they increase the number by the amount of landings performed. So for instance, you may have a single flight with one touch-and-go, one full stop landing. The line in the log book would read 10,787 - 10,788 for two landings.
Is this common practice, and why? Would you not usually number every entry through one by one?


Are you suggesting that if you logged 10 touch and goes on a single flight that it would be preferable to enter each one on a separate line?  Because that doesn't make sense, and would really string out the log book.  Standard practice in most log books is one line per "flight", however you choose to define that.  P.S.  I have been in several flying clubs and none have logged landings.  It's completely up to the club to decide this sort of thing, and I think any answer would be opinion based.

@MichaelHall He's in Germany and is referring to an aircraft log book where flights are recorded, not done in the US. In Canada we call it the Journey Log and every a/c has to have one. When you buy an airplane in Canada you have a complete record of all of its flights. If it's a homebuilt, like mine, you can use the J Log to record all maintenance as well, and skip the technical logs. The airplane's entire operating and maint history in one book. Anyway it looks like German requirements are to record TO/LDG cycles. In a Cdn JL you record each departure (and dest if CC) location as a flight.

@MichaelHall Not quite, if you logged 10 touch and goes the column for # of flight would read 10787 - 10797. In my mind it should only ever increase by one, but in this case it increases by the number of landings performed.

@DoubleM in the Transport Category world, takeoffs and landings, flight cycles, are a more important metric than total hours, mainly because most structural fatigue issues, and some system life issues, are more determined by up/down cycles (loading/unloading the structure or system on/off) than total hours. That's the only reason I can see for recording individual TOs and LDGs for tracking purposes and is very unusual for a light aircraft where fatigue isn't really a concern. That kind of recording might just be a club policy for their own reasons.

"In my mind it should only ever increase by one." Ok, but why do you think that? What does "Ltd. Nr. des Fluges" mean? It seems apparent that the club expects pilots to log the number of landings in the appropriately labeled column, do you simply disagree with this practice? Or do you believe members should never practice touch and goes?  It's not really clear why you are asking this question...

@MichaelHall "Lfd. Nr. des Fluges" literally means "Consecutive Number of Flight", as in "this is the nth flight performed with this aircraft". By nature I expect it to increase by one each line. The reason I'm asking is because I'm building SaaS that has a digital logbook feature. I want to understand the requirement behind this practice, and to find out whether it's common or local, so I know how to best attend to the requirement if at all. Seems to me like the reason is simply because there is no dedicated column for landings in this particular book. Thanks for your Canadian perspective!

Well it should be simple then:  If you are creating a digital logbook just include a field for the number of landings and let the user decide whether it is desired or required to log them.  But don't call it "Lfd. Nr. des Fluges"!  ;)

@MichaelHall That's exactly what I'll do. Thank you for the help, Michael.

That appears to be a German operational log book. In Canada it's called a Journey Log. In the United States such a log is not required to be maintained, only the technical logs.  You should check with EASA requirements for Journey Logs.  In Canada you record the date, pilot's name, departure and arrival airport (which can be the same, obviously, if it's just a local flight), air time and flight time, and total accumulated air time.
The normal requirement when a Journey Log must be maintained is to record a flight as the period from engine start to shutdown, and thus touch and goes are not recorded as individual flights, unless the touch and go was at another airport.
The log book pictured appears to be designed to record flight cycles as well as total air time; perhaps that is a German requirement.

Thank you for taking the time to post such an elaborate answer, it's highly valuable to me. Very much appreciated!
